# What is the most obvious to declare a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have started to understand the 2D array and multi-dimensional array, some reference books mentioned it has different ways to declare them. Which methods will be declare the array more easier and easy to understand?

**method 1:**

```
      $pgmCode = array
            (
             "Item1"=>array("...","..."=>array("..."=>1)),
             ......
            )
```

Or **method2:**

```
      $A['ABC']['...'] = '3';
      $A['...']['...']['...'] = '2';
```

Furthermore, if I will build a database and calling the data as array store, which method will be preferred to use?

Thanks.

Comment: method1 is mostly uses because in definition its clearly shows the hierarchy in multidiamentional array

Comment: I'd prefer method 1 too. Good luck with the learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pgmCode = array(
    "item1" = array(
        "subItem1" => true,
        "subItem2" => array("subSubItem1", "subSubItem2"),
    ),
    "item2" = array(
        "subItem1" => true,
        "subItem2" => array("subSubItem1", "subSubItem2"),
    ),
);
```

Watchout with mixed use of array and string item in an array, if you will do a in_array() on a mixed variable array it will always return true if you don't use the strict mode of the function.

in your method 1

```
in_array("something", $pgmCode['Item1']); //return true
in_array("something", $pgmCode['Item1'], true); //return false
```

Comment: Wonderful, arrays could define by this way. Get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pgmCode = array
            (
             "Item1"=>array("...","..."=>array("..."=>1)),
             "Item1"=>array("...","..."=>array("..."=>1)),
             ......
            );
```

makes it more understandable.